# Где найти документацию Pillow, Tkinter, PyQT, OpenGL?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt, pillow

На каком сайте можно найти документацию для модулей ЯП Python (Pillow, Tkinter, PyQT, OpenGL)?

Comment: [Можете посмотреть сайты которые в метке tkinter используются](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/tkinter/info). Про PyQt вы можете использовать [оф сайт Qt](http://doc.qt.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для модуля из стандартной библиотеки документацию следует искать на https://docs.python.org/3/search.html?q=tkinter

Ссылку на официальную документацию для сторонних Питон пакетов можно найти на их PyPI странице, к примеру, нажав на Documentation на https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ мы попадём на https://pillow.readthedocs.io, нажав на Homepage — http://python-pillow.org/

Обратите внимание, для представленных примеров, которые являются обёртками над API, реализованных на других языках, подробное описание конкретных API вызовов не является специфичным для Питона. К примеру, для tkinter,  [список ресурсов из официальной документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#module-tkinter) содержит ссылку на [tcl/tk man страницу](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/contents.htm), показывающую доступные команды и список их опций (трансляция в Питон обычно прямолинейна).

Аналогично, помимо [документации специфичной для pyqt](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/) (ссылка доступна с https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/), описывающей особенности обёртки, основное описание находится на http://doc.qt.io/ (С++ API) Oбычно pyqt один в один повторяет соответствующие С++ вызовы, поэтому если к примеру перейти на другую обёртку, такую как [Qt for Python](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python), то многие вызовы останутся прежними.

Поиск [pypi  opengl](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=pypi+opengl) ведёт на https://pypi.org/project/PyOpenGL/, где указана homepage: http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/ Опять таки для практического использования API могут быть полезны и ресурсы неспецифичные для конкретной обёртки для Питона (к примеру, ["The Red Book"](http://www.opengl-redbook.com/) для основ).

Answer (score 0):

Первые три:

1. Tkinter - https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html
2. PyQt - http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/
3. Pillow - https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/